# AJAX Hash Submit Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm pretty sure it has to do with my core.js file with the ajax hashing url. But I'm trying to submit a form, but it's not submitting like I want it to. This is the core.js file:

```
// call init
$(init);


function init() {
    ajax_page_handler();
    page_load($(window.location).attr("hash")); // goto first page if #! is available
}

function page_load($href) {
    if($href != undefined && $href.substring(0, 2) == '#/') {
        // replace body the #content with loaded html
        $('#content').load($href.substring(2), function () {
            $('#content').hide().fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }
}

function ajax_page_handler() {
    $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
        $href = $(window.location).attr("hash");
        page_load($href);
    });

    // this allow you to reload by clicking the same link
    $('a[href^="#/"]').live('click', function() {
        $curhref = $(window.location).attr("hash");
        $href = $(this).attr('href');
        if($curhref == $href) {
            page_load($href);
        }
    });
}
```

The live viewing is over at www.krissales.com. The form is here: http://www.krissales.com/#/media/5.Testing-1

Hit the link "Post Comment", then you'll type info in, then hit comment, but it just refreshes, but doesn't submit it.

The steps I've taken to solve it was in the comment file, in the form action field, I inserted the tag `name="#content"` simply because that's the name of my div that I'm submitting to.

The original stuff is on http://blog.krissales.com/article/7.Testing-3-man ( where you can actually post a comment, and it'll work)

But apparently it's not working. Do you guys have a clue as to what it is that I'm doing wrong? thanks for your help in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple"
    });
</script>
<form action="#/media/article.php" name="#content" method="POST">

    Name:
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="name" class="userpass"/>
    <br /><br />
    Comment:
    <br />
    <textarea id="elm1" name="comment" rows="7" cols="30" style="width: 500px;"> 
    </textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment" class="button" />
    <input type="reset" name="submit" value="Reset" class="button" />

</form>
```

Comment: It's not preferred to use `.live`, but rather use `on()`. I tested posting comments on your link and it seems to be working fine, my comment posted with no problem...

Comment: Please give us the code you have used on SUBMIT button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current core.js handles changes in the URL hash, and it reroutes any links with a hash to load that relative path into `#content`. What's missing is code to redirect form submits to do the same thing (add this to `ajax_page_handler`):

```
 $('form').live('submit', function(e) {
    var $action = $(this).attr('action');

    if($action.substring(0, 2) == '#/') {
        // replace the #content with result of the form post
        $.ajax({
            url: $action.substring(2),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $('#content').html(data);
                $('#content').hide().fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
        // stop the real form submit from happening
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are not setting the ajax type on the file 'comment.php'.

you need...

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
        url: 'comment_ajax.php',
        data: { form_name: name, form_comment: comment },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#new_comment').prepend(data);
                        // close modal box
            // do other shit
            // kthnxbai
        }
    });
```

If type is not specified, it defaults to a GET request which will not post data. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the action attribute of your form like this :

```
<form action="script-handling-comment-data.php#/media/article.php" name="#content" method="POST">
```

For the moment, you're sending the comment data to http://www.krissales.com/ and i think the main page doesn't handle the comment posting.

Comment: I changed everything back to default. Nothing seems to be working.. I think my handler for the core.js isn't right when handling forms.....

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be handling links properly, but form submission isn't a link, you probably want to handle submission using `$(form).submit(function(){ ... })`

In your case, if you gave your form the id `form1`

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){
  var keyValues = $(this).serializeArray();
  var map = {};
  for(i in keyValues)
  {
    var value = keyValues.value;
    var name = keyValues.name;
    map[name] = value;
  }
  $.post($(this).attr('action'),map,function(){
    alert("Submitted values: " + $(this).serialize());
  });
  return false;
})
```

See [`serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and [`.submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) for more information